# How to create a new Native Application for Azure AD through the Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any way (using either PowerShell cmdlets or the Graph API) to create a Native Application for Azure Active Directory ? I'm looking for a way to automate creation of environments for my application

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graph API to create an Application in your directory. Here is the PowerShell script.

```
# Adding the AD library to your PowerShell Session.
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

# This is the tenant id of you Azure AD. You can use tenant name instead if you want.
$tenantID = "<your tenant id>"
$authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID" 

# Here, the username must be a user in your organization and with MFA disabled.
# And, it must have permission to create an AD application.
$username = "<your username>"
$password = "<the password of your username>"

# The resource URI for your token.
$resource = "https://graph.windows.net"

# This is the common client id.
$client_id = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

# Create a client credential with the above common client id, username and password. 
$creds = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" `
         -ArgumentList $username,$password

# Create a authentication context with the above authentication string.
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" `
         -ArgumentList $authString

# Acquire access token from server.
$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resource,$client_id,$creds)

# Use the access token to setup headers for your http request.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

# Send a request to create a new AD application.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST `
    -Uri "https://graph.chinacloudapi.cn/$tenantID/applications?api-version=1.6-internal" `
    -Headers $headers -InFile ./application.json
```

If you "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll" is in a different location, you should modify the path of `Add-Type`.

In "application.json", you should specify parameters for your application. Here is a simple sample.

```
{
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application",
  "objectType": "Application",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "allowActAsForAllClients": null,
  "appBranding": null,
  "appCategory": null,
  "appData": null,
  "appMetadata": {
    "version": 0,
    "data": []
  },
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  "displayName": "nativeClient",
  "encryptedMsiApplicationSecret": null,
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "homepage": null,
  "identifierUris": [],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoUrl": null,
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "publicClient": true,
  "recordConsentConditions": null,
  "replyUrls": [
    "http://www.microsoft.com"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null,
  "supportsConvergence": false
}
```

The "requiredResourceAccess" must be set exactly like above, otherwise your application will not be manageable by Azure classic portal. If you take a deep look at the Json file, you will find out that Native Application and Web App Application share the same API and properties. As long as you keep most of the fields the same as the above sample, Azure will create a Native Application for you. But, of course, you can modify the displayName and replyUrls.